# res.cookie is not working anyway i tried all ways to solve this

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, middleware, mern

I am not able to see cookies in browser which are set by res.cookie
below given is my code
but still i am not able to set cookies
how to set that

const token = generateToken(user._id);

```
  res.cookie("access_token", token).status(200).json({
    success: true,
    user,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie may not be visible in the browser's developer tools because it has not been set as a "secure" cookie. If you are developing on localhost or using an HTTP connection instead of HTTPS, your browser may not display cookies that are set as "secure" to prevent potential security vulnerabilities. Try setting the "secure" flag to false and see if that makes the cookie visible in the browser:

```
res.cookie("access_token", token, { secure: false }).status(200).json({
  success: true,
  user
});
```

Comment: now working i added httpOnly:true there and withCredentials:true
but when i check res.cookies.access_token it gives undefined

Comment: I think its req.cookies.access_token